# Using Euler's equation and vector identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

An unsteady incompressible inviscid ﬂuid ﬂow satisﬁes the continuity equation
$∇·\textbf u = 0$
and Euler’s equation
$$\frac{∂ \textbf u }{∂ t}
+(\textbf u·∇)\textbf u = −
\frac1ρ
∇p$$
where $\textbf u$ is the velocity, $t$ is time,
$ρ$
is the constant density and $p$ is pressure.

(i) If the ﬂow is also irrotational, show that the potential satisﬁes Laplace’s equation where the potential is deﬁned by $u = ∇ φ$.

(ii) Use Euler’s equation and the vector identity
$$∇(\textbf a·\textbf b) = (\textbf a·∇)\textbf b+(\textbf b·∇)\textbf a+\textbf a∧(∇∧\textbf b)+\textbf b∧(∇∧\textbf a)$$
to show that
$$\frac{∂φ }{∂ t}
+
\frac12
|∇ φ |^2 + \frac pρ
= \text{constant}$$

---

Is the first part simply $ \nabla \cdot \textbf u =0 = \nabla \cdot \nabla φ= \nabla ^2 φ =0$?

For the second part, I have tried for ages and can't seem to get it, are we allowed to cancel the grad from both sides. And I have no idea where the half comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the identity (ii) we have

$$∇(\textbf u·\textbf u) = 2(\textbf u·∇)\textbf u + 2\textbf u∧(∇∧\textbf u).$$

In irrotational flow , $∇∧\textbf u = 0$ and $\textbf u = \nabla \phi$.

Hence,

$$ 2(\textbf u·∇)\textbf u =∇\left(\textbf u·\textbf u\right) = ∇\left(|\nabla \phi|^2\right) \\ \implies (\textbf u·∇)\textbf u = ∇\left(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla \phi|^2\right).$$

Substitution in Euler's equation yields

$$\frac{\partial}{ \partial t} \nabla \phi + ∇\left(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla \phi|^2\right) + ∇\left(\frac{p}{\rho}\right)= 0 \\ \implies \nabla  H := \nabla \left(\frac{\partial}{ \partial t}  \phi + \frac{1}{2}|\nabla \phi|^2 + \frac{p}{\rho}\right)= 0.$$

Integrating each component of $\nabla H = 0$ we obtain the Bernoulli equation

$$\frac{\partial}{ \partial t}  \phi + \frac{1}{2}|\nabla \phi|^2 + \frac{p}{\rho} = C(t),$$

where "constant" $C$ is independent of position but may depend on time.

Comment: Hi please could you look at my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781561/finding-stagnation-points-and-stream-function because I am desperate in knowing how to do this question and my exam is coming very soon. I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: @snowman: I posted an answer.  It seems you may have figured most of it out.  However, it is not clear if you are still having a problem solving for the stream function.  You edited your post and included the solution, but I thought you were uncertain about how to eliminate $F$ and $G$.  Happy to help if you need it.