# Finding stagnation points and stream function

Tags: partial-derivative, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

[image]

Sorry for the lack of latex. The question I want to ask would need all this info and it would take very long to write it.

(a) Irrotational flow means $\nabla \times \textbf u =0$ so we can define potential to be $\textbf u =\nabla \phi$ and since it is irrotational and inviscid, the continuity equation holds so $\nabla \cdot \textbf u =0$ so the laplacian of the potential holds, $\nabla \cdot \textbf u =\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi=\nabla^2 \phi=0$.

(b) $u_r = U\cos \theta (1-a^3 / r^3)$ and $u_{\theta}=-U\sin \theta (1+a^3/2r^3)$

(c) $(r=a, \theta = 0)$ and $(r=a, \theta = \pi)$

(d) $ψ=\frac U2 \sin^2 \theta (r^2 - a^3/r)$

(e) Would it be something like this: [image]
I am mainly stuck on c, d, and e. I am a tiny bit unsure on part (a) but it seems to make sense. Please do say if not.

Please help.

Comment: It seems you are confused on the notation. $u_r$ and $u_\theta$ are the radial and angular components of the velocity, $u_r=u$ and $u_\theta=v$. You should have realised this because the formulas for $u_r$ and $u_\theta$ are partial derivatives of the velocity potential. For (d), I think you want $r^2-a^3/r$ inside your brackets. It comes out easily enough, your $g(\theta)$ is an arbitrary constant, $g$, and $f(r)=-U(r^2-a^3/r)/2+g$. I think you'll have to plot the streamlines to see what they look like.

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply, I edited my post, can you tell me if part (c) is now correct. I am mainly stuck on the part where you sketch the streamline family. So for the $ψ =0$ streamline, we have simply $r=a$ which is just a circle with stagnation point on the horizontal sides. What is the approach to finish off the streamline sketch? How do we find the arrows on this $ψ =0$ streamline to let us guess what the other streamlines look like.

Comment: Yeah I think c is correct. The $\Psi=0$ streamline is the circle $r=a$ and straight lines at $\theta=0$ and $\pi$. The origin is a singularity, and all streamlines inside the circle $r=a$ go through it. This flow is symmetric about the vertical and horizontal axes. You can find the flow directions by looking at the sign of $u_r$ and $u_\theta$.

Comment: @David the thing that is confusing is that the signs of the velocity components also depend on $U $. But we don't know the sign of that. We're not told of it is a positive or nonnegative or just a real number. What do you think?

Comment: @David I assumed U>0 and posted a pic of what I thought it would be. Is this right? It is not fully symmetric on the vertical axis like you said because of the arrows inside the circle, which is doubting my sketch...

Comment: I didn't think about the arrows when I said it was symmetric, so you could well be correct. It's quite common to put a source term in a velocity potential to create closed streamlines, and for inviscid flow, you can think of a streamline as a boundary/surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b), we can take partial derivatives of $\phi$ to obtain

$$u_r =  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = U \cos \theta - U\frac{a^3}{r^3} \cos \theta, \\ u_\theta = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta}= -U \sin \theta  - U\frac{a^3}{2r^3} \sin \theta.$$

For (c), on the surface of the sphere $r = a$ and the radial velocity component vanishes, $u_r(a, \theta) = 0,$ since this component is normal to the surface. This is apparent upon substituting $a$ for $r$ in the above expression for $u_r$.   The tangential component is

$$u_\theta(a, \theta) = -\frac{3}{2}U \sin \theta.$$

We have a stagnation points on the surface $r = a$ where both velocity components vanish: $\theta = 0$ (fore) and $\theta = \pi$ (aft).

For (d), we solve for the streamfunction using

$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta} = r^2 \sin \theta u_r = U\sin \theta \cos \theta \left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right) = \frac{U}{2} \sin 2 \theta\left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right)\\ \implies \psi = -\frac{U}{4} \cos 2 \theta\left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right) + F(r) \\ \implies \psi = -\frac{U}{4} (1 - 2\sin^ 2 \theta)\left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right) + F(r)  \\ \implies \psi = \frac{U}{2} \sin^ 2 \theta\left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right) - \frac{U}{4}\left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right)  + F(r)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} = -r \sin \theta u_\theta = U\sin^2 \theta\left(r + \frac{a^3}{2r^2} \right) \\ \implies \psi = U \sin^2 \theta \left(\frac{r^2}{2} - \frac{a^3}{2r} \right) + G(\theta),$$

We get a consistent solution by choosing

$$G(\theta) = 0, \\ F(r) = \frac{U}{4}\left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right),$$

and it follows that

$$\psi = \frac{U}{2} \sin^2 \theta \left(r^2 - \frac{a^3}{r} \right)$$

Comment: OP already found $\Psi$, what does this answer add?

Comment: Doesn't bother me :)

Comment: @RRL Thanks for the reply. For (a), what was wrong with what I did? I am a bit confused on how the question says "explain" rather than work out, so shouldn't we just explain why it is rather than find all the derivatives and sub them in the laplacian equation?

Comment: @snowman: Your argument for (a) is correct. I misread the question.

Comment: @RRL Thanks! Do you think my sketch is correct?

Comment: Yes.  If this is a solid sphere, there is no need for streamlines in the interior.  If its a droplet or bubble, then the direction of the arrows you drew on the interior axis are correct.  Above and below the axis, the streamlines inside look like closed loops tangential to the axis at the center with arrows matching the direction of flow outside.

Comment: @RRL So about the solid sphere you mentioned, if we were asked to explain how this ﬂow can be used to describe the ﬂow past a solid sphere, what would we need to say? Would we just say, there would be no flow inside the bubble (like you said) but everything else is the same?

Comment: I'm saying if its a solid sphere, then there is no fluid (hence no streamlines) inside.  If it is a liquid droplet or gas bubble, then there are streamlines inside because flow is transmitted to match the exterior tangential velocity component at the surface.

Comment: The configuration is most likely a solid sphere.

Comment: @RRL Hi, if we wanted to calculate the far-field velocity, how would we do this? And how, if at all, would it help with the sketch we did?

Comment: @snowman:  The far field- velocity was imposed as a boundary condition: $\mathbb{u} \to U \mathbb{e}_x$ as $r \to \infty$.  The streamlines will tend to straight lines parallel to the $x-$axis.  You have more or less indicated this in your sketch.  Take the limit of the solution as $r \to \infty$ and you get the equivalent $u_r = U\cos \theta, u_\theta = - U \sin \theta$.